# mount bind inside container is not reflecting outside container

Tags: docker

I am trying to bind host dir to some dir inside container and expecting changes done inside container should reflect on host.

Here is the steps I have followed

created /hostdir on host and run ubuntu container in privileged mode

```
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# mkdir /hostdir
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# docker run -itd --privileged --name ubuntu -v /hostdir:/hostdir:z ubuntu
76aebded33274e95a6f569d0831aee4df27e9f200a8fd0401448239bd6f5bf80
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# docker exec -it ubuntu bash
```

creating a container_dir inside container

```
root@76aebded3327:/# mkdir /container_dir
```

binding the two directory (successfull)

```
root@76aebded3327:/# mount --bind /container_dir /hostdir
```

creating a file named hello.txt inside /container_dir

```
root@76aebded3327:/# cd container_dir/
root@76aebded3327:/container_dir# touch hello.txt
```

its get reflected inside /hostdir as it is bind mount to /container_dir

```
root@76aebded3327:/container_dir# ls /hostdir/
hello.txt
```

exit container and check on host , is the same reflected

```
root@76aebded3327:/container_dir# exit

[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# ls /hostdir/
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# ls /hostdir/ | wc -l
0
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]#
```

the content are not getting reflected.
I am missing something or doing completely wrong, please help me in the right direction.

Comment: If I got it correctly, you're making the bind in the wrong order inside the container for this to work => `mount --bind /hostdir /containerdir`

Comment: for one who want to close this post please refer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did not vote for close but many people could also point you to [On topic](/help/on-topic) which clearly points out only programming questions should be asked on SO. Although it is always subject to interpretations, this question belongs IMO to https://superuser.com (which is the actual close vote reason that was used).

Answer (score 1):

Your bind mount made with `mount --bind /container_dir /hostdir` will override volume mount inside the container. You simply bind-mount `/container_dir` over it (same as when you mount e.g. `/boot` partition over `/boot` directory on your root filesystem); so anything you write to `/hostdir` from that point will go only to `/container_dir` inside container.

What you probably want to do is to swap `mount --bind` arguments or just make `/container_dir` a symlink to `/hostdir`. Or make `/container_dir` a Docker volume directly and save the hassle.

Comment: if I swap, then the content already present in /container_dir will get overwrite by /hostdir.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve above using bind mount type and bind-propagation=shared

```
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# docker run -itd --name ubuntu --privileged --mount type=bind,source=/hostdir,target=/hostdir,bind-propagation=shared ubuntu
2cb814f600ed261ae5e50fcdaec6b5a5a17f3d41d37be307765e20274d918a25
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# docker exec -it ubuntu bash
root@2cb814f600ed:/# mkdir /container_dir

root@2cb814f600ed:/# touch /container_dir/hello
root@2cb814f600ed:/#  mount --bind --make-shared /container_dir /hostdir
root@2cb814f600ed:/# ls /hostdir/
hello
root@2cb814f600ed:/# exit
exit
[root@nhbdlin03 ~]# ls /hostdir/
hello
```